# SAXParseException - Content is not allowed in prolog in bamboo serverlog

Tags: java, xml, jmeter, bamboo, jmeter-3.2

SAXParseException  - Content is not allowed in prolog in bamboo server log.

I have run Jmeter script and working fine locally. when running with bamboo server below exception given.

**note: xml validation success**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="3.2" jmeter="3.2 r1790748")
<hashTree>
          -------------------
          -------------------
<name>SAXParseExceQtion</name>
<failure>true</failure>
<error>false</error)
<failureMessage>Content is not allowed in prolog.
See log file for further details.</failureMessage>
```

[full bamboo server log1 attached click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBM9o.jpg)

[full bamboo server log2 attached click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBLVl.png)

Bamboo Configuration is given below,

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin:$PATH
echo "========================= Part 1 ================"
sh apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/jmeter \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml \
-n -t SWISSUniversalAPI.jmx \
-l ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/SWISSUniversalAPI.jtl
echo -e "/////////////////////////////TEST LOG DETAILS////////////////////////"
cat SWISSUniversalAPI.jtl
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -jar m2u.jar --input ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/SWISSUniversalAPI.jtl --output ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/SWISSUniversalAPI.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't contain enough details to guess the reason, most probably it is connected with incorrect [.jtl result file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults). JMeter by default stores its results in .jtl format and Bamboo seems to be expecting XML. So try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

Check out [How to Run JMeter in a Continuous Integration Environment With Bamboo](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-continuous-integration-environment-bamboo) article for more information on adding JMeter load test to Bamboo builds.

Comment: @Dimitri T i have changed the property file but same issue here. FYI i have added full bamboo server log and configuration plan in the Question body see –